# Failed to install php7.0-soap on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, php7

when I

```
sudo  apt-get install php7.0-soap
```

I get the following errors:

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ wily/main php7.0-soap amd64 7.0.7-2+donate.sury.org~wily+1
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.0/php7.0-soap_7.0.7-2+donate.sury.org~wily+1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Any suggestion to fix this?

Answer (score 9):

You are getting a `404  Not Found` error message because there isn't a package named php7.0-soap in the **ppa:ondrej/php** PPA. php7.0-soap is provided by the php7.0 package from ppa:ondrej/php.

#### Installation in Ubuntu 12.04/14.04/15.10

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

#### Installation in Ubuntu 16.04→17.04

SOAP module for PHP (*php7.0-soap*) is a separate package in the default repositories for Ubuntu 16.04 and later. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install php7.0-soap
```

#### Installation in Ubuntu 17.10→18.04

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install php7.1-soap
```

Comment: I'm also running Ubuntu server 14.04 using the same repo ( ppa:ondrej/php ) and there is a package called php7.0-soap. There's even php7.1-soap

Comment: I'm not the one getting the error - it's Whaaaaat. Also I just installed the package from this repo (which is the only non-default one on this machine) without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're either not running 14.04 or you have the wrong repo added because in your error it says it's looking for `7.0.7-2+donate.sury.org~wily+1` which is for Ubuntu 15.10

The current version of the package for 14.04 is `7.0.9-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1`

If you're running 15.10 all you have to do is update apt's package list with `sudo apt-get update` before installing the package.

And if you're running 14.04 you have to edit the repo file located in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` starting with `onrej` (probably named `ondrej-php-willy.list`) and replace `willy` with `trusty` and then run `sudo apt-get update` before installing the package.